# How to filter categories from this model in views.py

Tags: mongodb, django-models, django-forms

In this function I'm not able to filter Categories alone. So please tell me how to do that? Here I used array model field for categories as well as specifications. From this array model field I could not get the categories column using query

```
set category_name=Product.objects.values_list('categories', flat=True).distinct()
```

And in that filter should be distinct values. So what query has to given for retrieving this categories values

**models.py**

```
 class Product(models.Model):
           name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
           image = models.ImageField(upload_to = '',blank="True")    
           categories = models.ArrayModelField(
               model_container=Categories,
               model_form_class=CategoriesForm
       )
       specifications = models.ArrayModelField(
           model_container=Specifications,
           model_form_class=SpecificationsForm
       )
       description = models.TextField()
       reviews = models.ArrayModelField(
           model_container=Reviews,
           model_form_class=ReviewsForm
       )
       drizzly = models.BooleanField()
       complete = models.BooleanField()

       def __str__(self):
           return self.name
    class Categories(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

       class Meta:
           abstract = True
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    data = Product.objects.all()
    category_name=Product.objects.values_list('categories', flat=True).distinct()      
    return render(request, 'db.html', data':data,'category_name':category_name})
```